# 2 Inline fancybox, second fancybox get error "The requested content cannot be loaded"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

The second fancybox will give me an error "The requested content cannot be loaded" the register. The inlog fancybox works fine for me what's the problem? I Googled it they said something with iframe type but when I do that the loading icon will rotate constantly and don't show the content.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.inlog").fancybox({ 
        maxWidth    : 250,
        maxHeight   : 100,
        fitToView   : false,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none'
    });
}); 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.register").fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 250,
        maxHeight   : 100,
        fitToView   : false,
        autoSize    : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none' 
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="login-bottom"> <a class="decoration inlog" href="#inlog"><span class="knop-text">login</span></a>

    <div id="inlog" style="display: none;">
        <form class="form" action="">
            <label>Gebruikersnaam:</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="fname" />
            <br />
            <label>Wachtwoord:</label>
            <input class="input" type="password" name="lname" />
            <br />
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="login" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="login-bottom"> <a class="decoration register" href="#register"><span class="knop-text">registreer</span></a>

    <div id="#register" style="display: none;">
        <form class="form" action="">
            <label>Gebruikersnaam:</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="fname" />
            <br />
            <label>Wachtwoord:</label>
            <input class="input" type="password" name="lname" />
            <br />
            <label>LoL gebruikersnaam:</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="fname" />
            <br />
            <label>E-mail:</label>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="fname" />
            <br />
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="login" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to a specific selector using `#` for *IDs* or `.` (dot) for *classes* in your jQuery code but not in your html so this

```
<div id="#register" ...
```

should be this

```
<div id="register" ...
```

working after correction **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/23H34/1/)**

Comment: thanks it helped me. i have an other question, I want a link in the register fancybox when they click on it i want that login fancybox wil open. is that possible?

Comment: @RudolfWardanjan : yes you can do that, but only a single fancybox can be open at the same time so the first will close to open the second. Also beware of this bug https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/672